# Не работают изменения с apache

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

В этом файле: /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Добавил изменение:

```
Alias /namepage /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
Allow from 00.000.00.000
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

После перезагрузки сервера ничего не изменилось. Перезагружал через ispmanager. Что не так делаю?

Comment: Что ты хочешь сделать? Что не изменилось?

Comment: хочу переименовать дефолтное название и добавить ограничение по IP-адресу на вход. Зашёл в apache.conf , внёс изменения, перезагрузил сервер и ничего не изменилось. Без проблем доступна phpmyadmin страница

Comment: Попробуй так:
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from твой ip